# Vue.js bind v-model input with prop initial value

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to pass down a initial value to a select input bound by `v-model`. I cannot figure out why this doesn't work:

```
props: ['team'],
data() {
    form: {
        data: {
            country: this.team.country
        }
    }
}
```

The `form.data.country` is `undefined`. Although, the props data is actually passed down. I can access it with *Vue Devtools* like `$vm0.team.country` and I can print other data from the props. However, it is not registred in the `data()`.

Also, when trying to debug using `mounted()`, the property, `team`, is not defined.

```
mounted() {
    console.log(this.team); 
}
```

But, as I stated earlier, it is defined when the template is rendered, and can be used like this.

```
<input class="input" type="text" name="name" :value="team.name" disabled>
```

Why is the properties I am passing not beinged recognized in `data()`?

Comment: Did you forget to `return` an object from the data function?

Comment: No, I do return an object. return {
                form: {
                    isLoading: false,
                    data: {
                        country: this.team.country
                    }
                }
            }

Comment: Is `team` populated asynchronously? You said an initial value bound by `v-model`; could you show how you are doing that? It would be helpful to have a working example.

Comment: However, based on the information given, my expectation is that `team` is initially undefined, then later set. That would explain why `this.team` is undefined in mounted and never defined in data. The data function is only called once when the component is created.

Comment: You are correct. The props data was asynced loaded by the parent. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The props data was asynced loaded by the parent. This was suggested in a comment by @Bert

Answer (score 0):

The asynchronous loading is not the problem. Even if team is hardcoded above, [it's still undefined](https://jsfiddle.net/np9L50sb/) when data is created in the component. (The component needs to be created before the root Vue that passes the prop.)

There is, perhaps someone will correct me, *never a good reason to reference props in your data.* **Something is either data** (the current component knows where to find what it wants) ***or* it's a prop** (the component will let it's context supply the info).

Then, as you've discovered, your data is created once. Vue watches everything for changes, but you're vulnerable to changes of the root value. If the thing referenced as a value when data is created, changes, the reactive pipe is broken. The answer to this is the [store pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47630933/1585345). You watch a variable in global scope, that never gets replaced, even though it's contents may change.

```
code
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18220708)

Comment: "The answer to this [question] is [to use] the store pattern".