# Is it possible to sync a child component with another in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have created a visual aid to help explain what my ideas are (please ignore the spelling mistake):
[image]

My idea is that you can select a recipient from a list and update another component with the information of the recipient selected. Now I had attempted this and I keep having trouble with a particular error `Uncaught TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object`.

So now I'm thinking that this is not possible?

Update:

```js
Vue.component('ChatRecipientList', {
  template: 'Set the recipient to "Jamie"',
  name: 'list-component',
  props: {
   recipient: null
  },
  mounted() {
   recipient = 'Jamie';
  }
})

Vue.component('MessagesView', {
  template: 'Showing messages for <span>{{ recipient }}</span>',
  name: 'show-messages-component',
  props: {
   recipient: null
  }
})

Vue.component('ChatContainer', {
  template: '<h1>Chat</h1>' +
   '<list-component :recipient.sync="this.recipient" />' +
    '<show-messages-component :recipient.sync="this.recipient" />',
  name: 'chat-container',
  data() {
  return { recipient: null }
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <chat-container/>
</div>
```

Thanks,
Jamie

Comment: It's perfectly possible to do it, could you please provide a JSFiddle for us to work on ?
Basically, you `Messages view` component will have a simple prop and will display it and your `Chat Recipient List` will send an event when modified, so the parent component will be able to update the value.

Comment: Only image wouldn't be meaningful to us. Always provide the code / code-snippet in the question itself

Comment: I have edited my post with the JSFiddle, although having trouble. I've never used JSFiddle for VueJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using vue 1. Using `.sync` modifier on the props for two way data binding causes maintainable issues and breaks tye rule of [one-way data flow](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow). Update to vue2 and make use of events to modify the prop value in the parent component.

You can use `.sync` modifier in vue 2.3 + , but its just syntactic sugar for [custom event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events) listener emitted by event.

Here is your code using `$emit` to emit an custom event to modify the prop(used vue 2.0+)

```
Vue.component('ChatRecipientList', {
  template: '<div>' + 'Set the recipient to "Jamie"' + '</div>',
  name: 'list-component',
  props: {
      recipient: null
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$emit('set-recipient', 'jamie');
  }
})

Vue.component('MessagesView', {
  template: '<div>' + 'Showing messages for {{ recipient }}' + '</div>',
  name: 'show-messages-component',
  props: 
      ['recipient']
  
})

Vue.component('ChatContainer', {
  template: '<div>' + 
  '<h1>Chat</h1>' +
      '<chat-recipient-list :recipient="recipient" @set-recipient="setRecipient" />' +
    '<messages-view :recipient="recipient" />' +
    '</div>',
  name: 'chat-container',
  data() {
        return { recipient: null }
  },
  methods:{
      setRecipient(event){
          this.recipient = event;
      }
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jvb7udjy/).

If you want to share the state among different component, mutating it in different components you can try [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html) for state management

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed. My project actually uses Vue 2, I just rushed the JSFiddle I created.

Comment: Although I can't seem to emit from inside a method, any ideas? I get a `Uncaught TypeError: _this.$emit is not a function` error

Comment: @JamieBonnett can you show you method and where it is invoked?

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, I may have gotten my Babel function wrong. Strangely enough the function was doing some of the functionality that I set it to do.

Answer (score -1):

Where is your store? Please don't try to do this without a store. Whenever you have state shared between components, [the store should be your central repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47630933/1585345).

Comment: I'm not looking to implement store functionality as of yet. For various reasons.

Comment: Are you confusing "store" with "redux store"? Implementing a redux store has a reputation for being tricky, and can be put off. Using vue with a store is much easier than the alternative. Trying to hold your state in vue components, and pass it around with props and events, will get messy very quickly. It's like trying to get a string puppet to work without the strings.