# Vue Js : Passing Data among siblings

Tags: vuejs2

Is there any other way to pass data between 2 siblings without using event bus or parent component in vue js?

I know that it can be passed with the help of Props and event emission. It can also be passed with the help of event buses.

Comment: If you know that, why are you asking?

Comment: I was just curious to know if there are any other ways possible. Probably even better.

Comment: @AnshSarwal vuex?

Answer (score 1):

If it is complex you would go you Vuex is the best solution in my opinion. However, if you just want a simple way to communicate between the components, you can simply go for OO Shared State. This is just a class that maintain your data that you can access from any components just pass it though, similar to singleton concept it OOP. There is a good example how to do this in Laracast website; have a look here https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/24.

Answer (score 0):

A general question is going to get a general answer. You need to ask yourself why your siblings need to talk to each other. Most often it's because you're not using a store. It would be a mistake to think of vue components like objects in an OO language. Vue components are fed via reactive pipes [from a store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47629353/two-components-binding-vuejs/47630933#47630933), the store is not a vue component. If you're doing this correctly, you don't often need to pass stuff between vue components.