# Vue: Render component differently, depending on parent components

Tags: vuejs2

I have multiple variants of cards in my app. Each card contains common sub-components (text blocks, avatars, images)

I want to assign specific css classes to a component when it is a sibling (not necessary a direct child) of specific card component.

Or add some html wrapper elements when component is rendered in specific card.

What is a recommended way to achieve this?

Or must one create different components for each card variant?

Comment: I can think of: apply styles as props? and add a container (which you already mentioned)

Comment: It really depends how different you want them to be. If you can simply hardcode the style differences with CSS classes, simply adding `class="..."` to your component should work. Otherwise, you might want to look into using mixins for your components.

Comment: yes, having a container parent component that "orchestrates" the children is the way to go

Comment: Please don't do this. Shared state should be in a store. Vue components shouldn't know or care about their siblings. Get your state into a store.

Comment: @bbsimonbb Can I have an example?

Comment: I think @bbsimonbb is referring to using Vuex, otherwise I'm just projecting, in which case, I would recommend that you use Vuex. There are many examples of use on the page https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/

Comment: @Daniel But how is it state? It's a static markup

Comment: the class name can come from a state. It's hard to go much deeper without understanding your setup.

Comment: Lots of folk think store = vuex = too difficult/leave for later. State in a global variable, described first up in [the docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html) , is overlooked as folk race to encapsulate. In fact, state in a global variable is a [*really good pattern*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47630933/1585345) for a lot of situations. In your case, if a sibling cares about the presence of another sibling, then this presence/absence is "shared state" - state that has repercussions beyond a single component. You're getting into exactly the problems that come from no store.

Answer (score 0):

So i believe you have a card component which has some common components and these components needs to look different in different cases.

for example let me assume these cards will hold user details which is their avatar image, his/her name which can be editable etc. now these cards are required should look different for men and women

Approach 1 - adding classes:

```
Vue.component('my-card', {
    props: {
      cardType: String,
    },
    data: function(){
      return {
        menCardClasses: {
            input: {'some-class': true}
        },
        womenCardClasses: {
            input: {'other-class': true}
        },
        inputClasses: {}
      }
    },
    computed: {
      if(this.cardType == 'men'){
        this.inputClasses = this.menCardClasses.input;
      }
    },
    template: `<div class='card'><input :class="inputClasses"></div>`
});
```

In this approach your card component will deal with state and the classes child components get

Approach 2 - wrapper component:

```
Vue.component('my-card', {
    props: {
      cardType: String,
    },
    data: function(){

    },
    computed: {

    },
    template: `<div class='card'>
                <men-card-component v-if="cardType=='men'"></men-card-component>
                <women-card-component v-else></women-card-component>
               </div>`
});

Vue.component('men-card-component', {
    template: `<div class='men-card'><input /></div>`
});

Vue.component('women-card-component', {
    template: `<div class='women-card'><input /></div>`
});
```

In this approach card component is just a wrapper which will render the another component based on the state.

You can pick the approach which suits you and make you feel comfortable.