# How to pass data from one vue component to another vue component without using the component tag

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I want to pass data from my vue file to another component which is present in the layout part. I know i can use props but for using props I need to initialize the component in the vue file from which I want to pass the data. But I don't want to initialize the component on my Vue I just want to pass the data.

here is the below structure. 
in my default.vue i have these 2 components.

```
  <right-side-bar-org  v-if="$route.name=='organisation'"></right-side-bar-org>
  <right-side-bar-search  v-if="$route.name=='search'"></right-side-bar-search>
```

I have declared the component with props. 
But for passing props i have to pass it from my default.vue. 
But i have this another component search.vue from which i want to pass the data to these components without declaring the component in the search vue.
Is there any way to make that happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These problems happen because [you're not using a store](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47630933/1585345). Put the data in a new location outside vue, in global scope. Then vue stuff can bind to it when created, unhook when destroyed, and different vms don't even need to know about each other.