# Vuejs watcher order

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, watch

I have a Vue instance with two watchers:

```js
watch: {
    zone:function(zone) {
        console.log('Zone watcher');
        this.route = {};
    },
    route:function(route) {
        console.log('Route watcher');
        if(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(route).length === 0) {
            var _this = this;
            axios.get(route.url).then(function(response) {
                _this.tracks = response.data;
            });
        } else this.tracks = {};
    }
},
```

When a user selects a zone, route (and tracks) are reset. When user selects a route, tracks are loaded;

I have a component receiving `zone` and `tracks` as props, also with two internal watchers that perform some independent actions when any of this props change.

I also have a method that changes both variables:

```
jump:function(path) {
    var parts = path.split(',');
    this.zone = this.ZONES[parts[0]];
    this.route = this.zone.routes[parts[1]];
},
```

The problem is watcher for `route` is fired in first place, then the watcher for `zone` changes `route` value triggering its watcher again, reseting `tracks` value to an empty object.

Is there a way to define the order that watchers must be triggered?

Comment: Don't mutate other watched variables inside a watcher - use methods instead. Also you use asynchronous server call using `axios` in a watcher - another no-no. Split things into different chunks and call them one after another (using promises for example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Andrey's comment shows the way. This question comes down to which tools you use for what job. Inevitably there's a bit of opinion... `watch` is for edge cases. You don't need it often, and if you can do without it, you probably should. `watch` belongs with computed and v-bind: they're reactive, use them (only) for representing state on screen, you have no (or little) control over when they run, and you shouldn't care.

A server request belongs in a method, or in a function outside of Vue ([in your store perhaps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47630933/1585345)) where it can be called explicitly. So create yourself a changeZone() function that clears routes and tracks, then calls the server, then updates your data (or store) with the server response. Your code will be much clearer if these little functional sequences are specified explicitly, in one place. The trigger for your sequence should likely be from an event (user-action) or lifecyle hook, not a watch.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. It made me restructure a little bit how everything works and it's now a lot more logical (and I would want to think less buggy)