# Vue watcher's first callback not ordered "correctly" on post-instantiation watchers

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, watch, vue-reactivity

I have the following doubt, regardless of the quality of the code or the best practices not followed.

I have a Vue component with two watchers. One of them is declared on the component's `watch` object (Therefore instantiated at its creation), and the other one is instantiated at the `mounted()`, in order to avoid calling it on the first mutation.

```
data: {
  return() {
    watchedAtInit: null,
    watchedAfterMount: null,
  };
},

mounted() {
  api.fetchSomething().then((response) => {
    this.watchedAtInit = response.watchedAtInit;
    this.watchedAfterMount = response.watchedAfterMount;
    this.$watch('watchedAfterMount', this.watchedAfterMountMethod);
  });
},

watch: {
  watchedAtInit() {
    // something
  }
}

methods: {
  watchedAfterMountMethod() {
    this.watchedAtInit = someValue;
  },
}
```

The problem here is at the end: The watched variable `watchedAtInit` is being mutated from another watcher `watchedAfterMountMethod`, which I understand is [not good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51155011/vuejs-watcher-order).

Still, something strange happens when mutating `watchedAfterMount`:

- The first time I mutate `watchedAfterMount`, the **`watchedAtInit()`** watcher is called **before** the **`watchedAfterMountMethod()`**, despite the mutation of `watchedAtInit` occurs at the `watchedAfterMountMethod`.
- In further `watchedAfterMount` mutations, the order is indeed as expected: the `watchedAfterMountMethod` is called, which mutates `watchedAtInit`, therefore triggering its watcher.

¿Why is the `watchedAfterMount` watcher delaying at its first mutation? ¿Does it have something to do with Vue's reactivity system, or is it merely the result of an incorrect implementation of watchers?

¿Could I be missing anything else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watchers won't be intialized on mounted by default, but you can force this behaviour writing your watchers like this:

```js
watch: {
  watchedAtInit: {
    immediate: true,
    handler() {
    // something
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was looking for. Therefore, if not given the "inmediate: true" property, the watcher will be initialized when the watched variable is first mutated, correct?

Comment: The watcher will be triggered by data that is changed after the mounted hook. So it won't be triggered by what is happening in the mounted hook.