# Vue: When an object has many properties, how do you pass it as a prop to a child?

Tags: vue.js

How does a parent pass an object to a child when that object has numerous properties?

I don't want to use the "Passing properties of an object" syntax, `v-bind="myObject"`, because I would have to define all the properties in the child individually (for validation), and the list would be too long.

I don't want to use the "Pass an object" syntax, `v-bind:myObject="myObject"`, because I need to change the values of the properties in the child, which would mutate them in the parent, and thereby violate the principle of 'events up, mutations down'.

I could pass the entire object to the child, then make a local copy of the properties (by returning them in the child's data property) and modify those.  But then when I make mutations in the parent (using an event bus), they are not propagated to the child.  (In other words, the child's data properties are no reactive).

Are there other options?

Comment: if the child's data properties are reactive, it would override the local modification. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: @JacobGoh I have an array of similar objects in the parent.  Each one constitutes its own child component.  The user updates fields in the child, and saves them with an ajax call.  The ajax call returns the freshly saved copy of the record, which I pass to the parent via the event bus.

Comment: [Are you trying to use Vue without a store?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47630933/1585345)

Comment: @bbsimonbb I am not using a store - although the props are large, its a simple parent/child relationship, with no other real complications.

Comment: Parent-child relationships are never simple ;-) A store would be simpler.

Answer (score 2):

this functionality is possible with vue's existing `v-bind` functionality

```
<!-- pass down parent props in common with a child component -->
<child-component v-bind="$props"></child-component>
```

this will pass all the props, which is helpful if you have a wrapper component and want to pass down all props to the child. You can also use a computed value to generate an object if you want to include/exclude data or props.

docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind